# how to search value of variable in array using perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have following result in array @bgp_status

```
Neighbor        V    AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
::100:1:1:2     4   100       6       6       21    0    0 00:00:15       10
::200:1:1:2     4   200       6       6       21    0    0 00:00:10       10
```

Now i want to know what is the value of State/pfxRcd ?? that is 10 here. I want to extract value of state for both ::100:1:1:2 and ::200:1:1:2 neighbours.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: What's exactly in the array? Individual lines? Columns?

Comment: Hi Choroba and Dave , Thanks for your time on this. well I have tried this way ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean each row is an entry in the array, then code like this will work:

```
my @bgp_status = ("Neighbor V AS MsgRcvd MsgSent TblVer InQ OutQ Up/Down State/PfxRcd",
                  "::100:1:1:2 4 100 6 6 21 0 0 00:00:15 10",
                  "::200:1:1:2 4 200 6 6 21 0 0 00:00:10 10");
my @states = ();
for my $line (@bgp_status) {
    if ($line =~ /^::\d/) { # Check if it's an IP row
        $line =~ /(\d+$)/; # Assuming last # in row is state
        my $state = $1;
        push(@states, $state);
    }
}

print @states;
```

You can refactor this to be shorter, or more robust, or use some sort of data structure to also save the IP:State association. I like to leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thanks for help and it works well for present scenario, may be i have to take care of to match any ip address in begining not only ^::. i will do it. Regards !! Satish